# How to hover from hidden to block in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

how to change hidden element to block element in tailwind

i have try this but not work
`

```
.bs .bsx .limit .ply {
        @apply hidden absolute w-full z-[1] h-full top-0 bg-black/[0.51] hover:block;
    }
```

im also try this but its still not work

```
.bs .bsx .limit .ply {
       @apply invisible absolute w-full z-[1] h-full top-0 bg-black/[0.51] hover:visible;
}
```

`

i have try other except hidden to block but all work, only hidden to block not work

Comment: Hidden element is not interactive despite it presents in DOM. You may however hover parent or sibling element in order to hidden element to appear (both parent and sibling should have at least 1px height)

Answer (score 0):

Visible isn't an option in Tailwind. You would have to make the default hidden then make it block (or something else) on hover. Block is the default option for most elements without being specified I believe. So when you call hidden, it replaces the block property.
`<div className="hidden hover:block">Hello World</div>`

Comment: it still not work

Answer (score 0):

A hidden element is not rendered in the DOM, so it cannot be hovered by the mouse. Instead you set the display based on whether the parent element in hovered. I did this by adding `group` to the parent element, then `group-hover:block` to the hidden element.

```html
<div className="group">
    <p>Always visible</p>
    <div className="hidden group-hover:block">Visible on hover</div>
</div>
```

Found [here in the official tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state).